# Key methods selection in rpart

Tags: r, rpart

What's the rule to select the complexity parameter (`cp`) and method in `rpart()` function from the [`rpart`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=rpart)? I've read a couple articles regarding the package, but the contents was too technical for me to grok.

Example:

```
rpart_1 <- rpart(myFormula, data = kyphosis,
                 method = "class", 
                 control = rpart.control(minsplit = 0, cp = 0))
plotcp(rpart_1)
printcp(rpart_1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You typically don't *choose* the `method` parameter as such; it's chosen for you as part of the problem you're solving. If it's a classification problem, you use `method="class"`, if it's a regression problem, you use `method="anova"`, and so on. Naturally, this means you have to understand what the problem is you're trying to solve, and whether your data will let you solve it.

The `cp` parameter controls the size of the fitted tree. You choose its value via cross-validation or using a separate test dataset. `rpart` is somewhat different to most other R modelling packages in how it handles this. The `rpart` function does cross-validation automatically by default. You then examine the model to see the result of the cross-validation, and prune the model based on that.

Worked example, using the `MASS::Boston` dataset:

```
library(MASS)

# does 10-fold CV by default
Bos.tree <- rpart(medv ~ ., data=Boston, cp=0)

# look at the result of the CV
plotcp(Bos.tree)
```

[image]

The plot shows that the 10-fold cross-validated error flattens out beginning at a tree size of about 9 leaf nodes. The dotted line is the minimum of the curve plus 1 standard error, which is a standard rule of thumb for pruning decision trees: you pick the smallest tree size that is within 1 SE of the minimum.

Printing the CP values gives a more precise view of how to choose the tree size:

```
printcp(Bos.tree)

           #CP nsplit rel error  xerror     xstd
#1  0.45274420      0   1.00000 1.00355 0.082973
#2  0.17117244      1   0.54726 0.61743 0.057053
#3  0.07165784      2   0.37608 0.43034 0.046596
#4  0.03616428      3   0.30443 0.34251 0.042502
#5  0.03336923      4   0.26826 0.32642 0.040456
#6  0.02661300      5   0.23489 0.32591 0.040940
#7  0.01585116      6   0.20828 0.29324 0.040908
#8  0.00824545      7   0.19243 0.28256 0.039576
#9  0.00726539      8   0.18418 0.27334 0.037122
#10 0.00693109      9   0.17692 0.27593 0.037326
#11 0.00612633     10   0.16999 0.27467 0.037310
#12 0.00480532     11   0.16386 0.26547 0.036897
# . . .
```

This shows that a CP value of 0.00612 corresponds to a tree with 10 splits (and hence 11 leaves). This is the value of `cp` you use to prune the tree. So:

```
# prune with a value of cp slightly greater than 0.00612633
Bos.tree.cv <- prune(Bos.tree, cp=0.00613)
```